# Saving login time during user login with C# window form application

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlclient

Now I am trying to get the user log with C# window form Desktop application.
I tried

```
    private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = txt_Username.Text;
        string password = txt_Password.Text;

        if (username=="" && password=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Username and Password");
        }
        else
        {

            Function.sqlfunction.connection.Open();
            string query = "adminlogin";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Function.sqlfunction.connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass_word", password);
            int usercount = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (usercount == 1)  
            {
                string loginsert = "INSERT INTO tbl_loguser (username, loginTime) VALUES (@username,@time)";
                SqlCommand logcmd = new SqlCommand(loginsert, Function.sqlfunction.connection);
                logcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                logcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                logcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Form next = new frm_Discount();
                next.Show();
                this.Hide();                    

            }
            else
            {



                MessageBox.Show("LoginId or Password Is wrong"); //if user Name is not available in database

            }
            Function.sqlfunction.connection.Close();

        }
    }
```

I can enter into  my application, no data was save to tbl_logusers
how should I do next.Please help me with this .

Comment: note: using local machine time is not reliable, use server time GETDATE() instead

Answer (score 7):

As far as I see, you *never* execute your command. You need;

```
logcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

after you add parameter values.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` instead of calling `.Close()` method manually.

And don't use `AddWithValue` anymore. [It *may* generate unexpected results](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use [`.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or it's overloads.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   // Set your CommandText propert of your query.
   // Add your parameter values with SqlParameterCollection.Add() method
   // Open your connection.
   // Execute your query.
}
```

I strongly suspect you try to save your `DateTime` value as a character in your `time` column. Don't do that! Pass your `DateTime.Now` value ([`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *might* be preferable of course) directly to your `datetime` or related typed column.

Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: I change the format of datetimepicker into (dd/mm/yy) format and put into date typed column of SQL server.But i when I query back , it appear with time , how can I do to get only date . In DB it show only date . Can you show me a way.